# Matrix times Vector where the elements are vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensor-products, hadamard-product

Whats the correct operation to calculate the "product" of matrix $A$ of the size $M \times L$

$$A=  
\begin{bmatrix}
\vec{A}_{1,1} & \vec{A}_{1,2} \\
\vec{A}_{2,1} & \vec{A}_{2,2} \\
\vec{A}_{3,1} & \vec{A}_{3,2} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
where the elements are vectors of the form
$$\vec{A}_{1,1} = \begin{bmatrix}A_{1,1}^1, A_{1,1}^2,...,A_{1,1}^N
\end{bmatrix}$$
(where the entries like $A_{1,1}^1$ are a complex number)

with a vector $b$ of the size M $$b=\begin{bmatrix}
\vec{b_1}\\
\vec{b_2}\\
\vec{b_3}
\end{bmatrix}$$
where the elements of $b$ are vectors too for example
$$\vec{b_1}=\begin{bmatrix} 
b_1^1, b_1^2, ... ,b_1^N
\end{bmatrix}$$
(where the entries like $b_{1}^1$ are a complex number)

such that

$$A^T \bullet b = \begin{bmatrix}
\vec{A}_{1,1} \odot  \vec{b}_1 + \vec{A}_{2,1} \odot  \vec{b}_2 + \vec{A}_{3,1} \odot  \vec{b}_3\\
\vec{A}_{1,2} \odot  \vec{b}_1 + \vec{A}_{2,2} \odot  \vec{b}_2 + \vec{A}_{3,3} \odot  \vec{b}_3
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $\odot$ denotes the hadamard product (elementwise multiplication of two vectors of the same length).

My questions are:

1. Is there such an operation?
2. What is the correct mathematical notation to define such an operation
3. Is this somehow easier to write? For example as a Tensor - Matrix
   operation where $A \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times L \times N}$ and $b \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times N}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\o{{\tt1}}$The dimension $M$ must be factorable such that the $b$ vector can be arranged as a block vector of $p$ partitions each of length $N$, i.e. $M=pN.\;$ In your example $\;p=3,\;N=M/p$.

Using all-ones vectors $({\rm eg}\;\o_p\in{\mathbb R}^{p})$,
Kronecker products $(\otimes)$, the identity matrix $\,\left(I_N\in{\mathbb R}^{N\times N}\right)$, and vectorization (aka column stacking),
the desired operation can be written as
$$\eqalign{
&{\rm vec}\Big(\big(\o_p\otimes I_N\big)^T\left(A\odot b\o_L^T\right)\Big)\\
&{\rm vec}\Big(\big(\o_p\otimes I_N\big)^T\,{\rm Diag}(b)\,A\Big) \\
}$$